# Xcode 7.Не создается связь между Button и объектом. В чем проблема?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple

Учу objective-c по книге BecomeAnXcoder. Дошел до шага создания кнопок и связывания их с созданным объектом.Это у меня сделать и не получается. Подробнее на скринах. Помогите пожалуйста.

[image]

Comment: А где скриншоты?

Comment: Как-то мало информации, возможно пропущены IBOutlet или не назначен класс объекту?